# SSH Connection time out

Tags: ssh, vps

Whenever I try to SSH my VPS account it says:

```
SSH connection time out during banner exchange.
```

I want to know the reason behind this problem and a solution. My VPS is running Ubuntu 12.04 Server and I am trying to connect from a Ubuntu 12.10 client. I am using key based authentication and SSH version is 2.

Comment: `ssh foo.com -v` for verbose output.